# No signal at 2560x1440 resolution from early 2013 Retina MacBook Pro

Tags: display, thunderbolt, resolution, displayport

I have an early 2013 Retina MacBook Pro running macOS Sierra 10.12.5 connected to an ViewSonic VX2478 monitor using a MiniDisplayPort cable connected to a ThunderBolt port.  The monitor is detected correctly as having a default resolution of 2560x1440.  However, when I set it to the default resolution the monitor claims to have no signal while macOS seems to think everything is fine.  If I set the resolution to 1080p the display works fine.

When I started trying to make this work I had El Capitan instead of Sierra.  The problem was slightly different.  The monitor didn't display a "No Signal" error, but it didn't display anything, either.

I connected the display to my Windows laptop using its ThunderBolt port and the full native resolution worked fine.

I have tried the following:

- Both a mini-DP to DP (included with the display) and a mini-DP to mini-DP cable (purchased new)
- Reseting NVRAM
- Reseting the SMC
- Both Thunderbolt ports
- Experimenting with various resolutions using SwitchResX
- Disabling Automatic Graphics Switching

I haven't tried using an HDMI cable because I can't seem to find one lying around, and many of the solutions I've found to similar problems involve using a DisplayPort cable instead of an HDMI or DVI cable.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes, just a couple minutes ago.  I used an HDMI cable.  I think you just need to make sure it's a sufficiently new/good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using an HDMI cable.  Full resolution works fine.  I still don't know why DisplayPort doesn't work at full resolution.